# find first populated cell in row then count blanks to next populated cell and pull in header

Tags: excel, excel-2010, offset

How would I find the first cell in a row containing a number, then count the blank cells until the next number, and if the count of blank cells is greater than 36 pull in the header from the populated cell that follows the blank cells.
In the next column I would then need a formula that starts at the populated cell following the 36 blank cells and does the same thing as above again i.e. counts the blank cells and if greater than 36 pulls in the header.
I am thinking that it might be offset function but unsure how to pull it together - or does it need to be VBA?

Comment: What do you return if the count of blank cells between two numbers is less than 36?

Comment: a zero is fine as I am only interested where there are more than 36 blank cells together in a block

Comment: I am using the following

Comment: I am using the following =IF(COUNTA(J59:DD59)>1,LARGE(INDEX(($J59:$DC59<>"")*COLUMN($J59:$DC59),0),1)-LARGE(INDEX(($J59:$DC59<>"")*COLUMN($J59:$DC59),0),2)-1,0) and then in the next column adjusting it to =IF(COUNTA($J59:$DD59)>2,LARGE(INDEX(($J59:$DC59<>"")*COLUMN($J59:$DC59),0),2)-LARGE(INDEX(($J59:$DC59<>"")*COLUMN($J59:$DC59),0),3)-1,0) however I am already up to 6 different columns and could go on for a lot more -

Comment: what I really need is just 2 or 3 columns of formulas where column 1 finds the first set of 36 blank cells in a row and column 2 contains the formula to find the second set of 36 blank cells in a row and column 3 contains the formula to find the 3rd set etc.. but I need it to stop at the last value in the row otherwise it counts all the blanks at the end where there is not another sale - sorry couldn't fit into a single comment

Comment: Hi. If J59:DC59 contains the data, which range contains the headers to be returned? J1:DC1?

Comment: Difficult! The only options I can think of are to set up a helper row for every row in your sheet to count spaces (i.e. a helper sheet), or VBA. I will try and post something if you think a helper sheet is of any interest.

Comment: Also, I'm a bit confused: J59:DC59 comprises a mere 98 columns, so I would've thought you could never have more than 2 results, right?

Comment: thank you @XOR_LX max of 2 results at the moment but it will increase to 3 and as I said I would like to have it in 2 columns but cant work out how to do it.  The column header is in row 3 (I have it filtered so that 59 is the first row that needs this formula).  I am happy to change references to suit my data if you are able to help with a formula example

Comment: So where are the results to go? In columns DD, DE, DF, etc.?

Comment: results are to go into columns B and C as I will be able to get rid of some of the columns where I am currently trying to work it out. It is not possible to put the calculations on the end as it causes a circular reference with some of the other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both **array formulas****:

In `A59`, used to determine the expected number of returns for that row:

`=COUNT(1/(MMULT(INDEX(MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(J59:DC59),{1;1}*COLUMN(J59:DC59))),N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNT(MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(J59:DC59),{1;1}*COLUMN(J59:DC59))))-1))+{0,1}))),{-1;1})-1>36))`

Copy down to give similar counts for rows 60, 61, etc.

Then, in `B59`:

`=IF(COLUMNS($A:A)>$A59,"",INDEX($3:$3,SMALL(IF(MMULT(INDEX(MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER($J59:$DC59),{1;1}*COLUMN($J59:$DC59))),N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNT(MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER($J59:$DC59),{1;1}*COLUMN($J59:$DC59))))-1))+{0,1}))),{-1;1})-1>36,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER($J59:$DC59),IF(COLUMN($J59:$DC59)>MIN(IF(ISNUMBER($J59:$DC59),COLUMN($J59:$DC59))),{1;1}*COLUMN($J59:$DC59))))),COLUMNS($A:A))))`

Copy down and also across (up to column I if required).

This set-up could probably be made more efficient by tailoring it to account for a maximum of two returns. In the end, however, I thought it was worth deriving a generic solution which will work for any number of returns (the range here - `J59:DC59` - can be extended as desired).

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: will try this and come back with comments - thank you for your time

Comment: This works beautifully thank you so much.  If you get a few minutes it would be good to know how the separate bits work as I haven't worked with MMULT or MODE>MULT before

Comment: Could I just also ask as I don't fully understand the formula - what happens if there are 2 sequences of 36 or more blank cells that fall between the first and last sales?

Comment: Sorry - not sure I understand your question. They will be returned as required, I imagine.

Comment: sorry, didn't make my query clear.  At the moment the header column for the value after the sequence of blanks is returned to column C cell if the blanks are more than36.  However if there are 2 sequences it will not be able to pull more than 1 header into column C.  Will it put a 2 in column B?

Comment: It pulls as many headers as match that criterion into separate cells, not a single cell, as described in my solution ("Copy down and also across (up to column I if required).", "...In the end, however, I thought it was worth deriving a generic solution which will work for any number of returns...")

Comment: You're welcome! It's quite a complex formula, so an explanation won't be that straightforward, I'm afraid, though I'll try to add some notes later.

Comment: That's ok, dont worry too much.  I can research when I have time.  Just to say though that where there is more than 1 sequence of 36 or more blanks it ignores the first sequence and lists the header for the second sequence.  That is not a problem for this instance though as we have changed our process so that it will still work for us.  Just advising should anyone else use this formula.  Thank you again for all your help

Comment: Recall that you said "find the first cell in a row containing a number, then count the blank cells until the next number, and if the count of blank cells is greater than 36 pull in the header from the populated cell that follows the blank cells.", so I hope you don't mean now that you expect the gap TO the first number to be included, which obviously does not meet the specifications you laid out.

Answer (score 0):

OK I will put in the helper version as an alternative.

Briefly here is a simplified sheet 1:-

[image]

and sheet 2 just counts spaces as mentioned and puts in a flag (-1) to show when a certain number of spaces has been reached:-

[image]

So in Sheet2!D2 the following formula adds one to the value in the cell to the left if the corresponding cell in Sheet1 is empty. If the corresponding cell in Sheet1 is not empty, it inserts -1 if the number of spaces has reached a certain number (in this example, 4).

```
=IF(Sheet1!D2="",MAX(C2,0)+1,IF(C2>3,-1,0))
```

The formula in Sheet1!B2 finds the first -1 in the corresponding row in Sheet2 and indexes the corresponding header in row 1:-

```
=INDEX($A$1:$P$1,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$D2:$P2<0,COLUMN($D2:$P2)),1))
```

The formula in Sheet1!C2 finds the second -1 : this could be made more general by using the current column in the SMALL function to find the nth -1. This is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=INDEX($A$1:$P$1,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$D2:$P2<0,COLUMN($D2:$P2)),2))
```

Needs error handling for the case that there are less than 2 sequences of empty cells.

Comment: will give this a try as well and decide which one does the job best - thank you again for your help